# Dashboard Login screen JAVA GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm sorry for my bad english.... I have created a login screen for my Java GUI Program. I stuck at the dashboard frame... I have no idea if I click the login button, it will be moved to a new frame... And is it possible if I make this sign up and sign in just only in 1 source java file?

That's all, Thanks

**Here's my code**

```
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Dashboard extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener, MouseListener {

//JPanel
JPanel SignPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
JPanel LoginPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));

//JLabel
JLabel gambar = new JLabel();
JLabel Userlbl = new JLabel("Username");
JLabel Passlbl = new JLabel("Password");

//TextField and Password
JTextField UserTxt = new JTextField(15);
JPasswordField PassTxt = new JPasswordField(15);

//JButton
JButton SigninBtn = new JButton("Sign In");
JButton SignupBtn = new JButton("Sign Up");
JButton SigninBtn2 = new JButton("Sign In");
JButton CancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");

public Dashboard() {
    super("Boutique");

    gambar.setIcon(new ImageIcon("\\Untitled.jpg"));
    add(gambar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    SignPane.add(SigninBtn);
    SignPane.add(SignupBtn);
    add(SignPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    setResizable(false);
    SigninBtn.addMouseListener(this);
    SignupBtn.addMouseListener(this);
}

public void signin() {
    JFrame Signin = new JFrame();

    LoginPane.add(Userlbl);
    LoginPane.add(UserTxt);
    LoginPane.add(Passlbl);
    LoginPane.add(PassTxt);
    LoginPane.add(SigninBtn2);
    LoginPane.add(CancelBtn);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Dashboard window = new Dashboard();
                window.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == SigninBtn){
        signin();
    } else {
        dispose();
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: `make this sign up and sign in just only in 1 source java file` That sounds like a good way to make things harder for yourself, not easier.

Comment: okay my bad, now I already fixed it.. thanks btw :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve.. Do you want to close the old window and open a new one when when the `SigninBtn` is clicked?

And by the way use the actionPerformed method instead of mouseClicked and If you're not using any of the other mehtods of the MouseListener then remove it.

```
SigninBtn.addActionListener(this);

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource().equals(SigninBtn)){
       signin();
    }
}
```